# Simple Javascript encrypt, PHP decrypt with shared secret key

Tags: php, javascript, algorithm, encryption

This is not about security. It is also not to make it hard to break. I'm looking for a simple algorithm to change a string (a url) in a way it does not resemble the original. The *encryption* will be done with javascript. Then I want to feed the *encrypted* string to a PHP function to change it back to the original. Both ends could share a secret key, or the conversions could be key-less and rely on just logic.

The ideal solution

1. will be simple
2. will use available javascript functions for encryption
3. will use available php functions for decryption
4. will produce encrypted string in way not to resemble the plain text at all
5. will only use lower-case alphabet characters and numbers in the encrypted string
6. is not a method widely used like Base64-ing as encryption.

Edit: The last requirement was added after [shamittomar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609005/simple-javascript-encrypt-php-decrypt-with-shared-secret-key/3609068#3609068)'s answer.

Comment: By doing this in javascript a client can easily view the source and decrypt your encrypted string.

Comment: @Chris - That would not pose a problem; as I stated in the question this is not for security or secrecy's sake.

Comment: this is why I posted it as a comment merely, to make sure you were aware that's all.  As others have said any hashing algorithm your javascript and php have available would work just fine.  md5, base64, sha will all work.

Comment: Note md5 and sha are one way hash algorithms, not applicable in this case because the OP wants to decrypt the encrypted string.

Comment: stupid question, what's the point of this? when it's not about secrecy or security and you dont want a common function for this just to weirdly encode it. I am just curious

Comment: @My1 in my country many sites are blocked. Back in the day this question was asked vpns were hard to come by and many had to rely on web proxies (themselves on http). The filtering was clever enough to reverse the base64 encoding of the target url and would block the request nevertheless. I had access to the source code of one such proxy (PHP) and wanted to change the method from base64 encoding to something different to get around this. Related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3568669/66580) and [this](https://serverfault.com/q/232872/25163).

Comment: well that is intresting. thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If that's what you want, you can **Base64** encode and decode that.

**[EDIT]: After OP clarification:**

As you do not want widely used methods, here is one *rarely* used method and that can do it for you by giving output only in LOWERCASE letters and NUMBERS. It is **[Base32 Encode/Decode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32)**. Use the following libraries:

- Javascript Base32 Encoder: http://www.tumuski.com/2010/04/nibbler/
- PHP Base32 Decoder: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/3484-PHP-Encode-and-decode-data-with-MIME-base-32-encoding.html

Comment: Thank you. I probably should have stated it in my question that widely used conversion methods are not suitable. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks! I will probably chain more than one method to get it unique.

Comment: PHP link is dead :(

Comment: @jonny, link is updated, thanks for bringing to my notice.

Answer (score 33):

You can use bitwise XOR in javascript to encode the string and again in PHP to decode it again. I wrote a little Javascript example for you. It works the same in PHP. If you call enc() a second time with the already encoded string, you'll get the original string again.

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function enc(str) {
    var encoded = "";
    for (i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        var a = str.charCodeAt(i);
        var b = a ^ 123;    // bitwise XOR with any number, e.g. 123
        encoded = encoded+String.fromCharCode(b);
    }
    return encoded;
}
var str = "hello world";
var encoded = enc(str);
alert(encoded);           // shows encoded string
alert(enc(encoded));      // shows the original string again
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In PHP do something like this (caution, this is not tested and it's been a long while since I did PHP):

```
$encoded = "...";   // <-- encoded string from the request
$decoded = "";
for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($encoded); $i++ ) {
    $b = ord($encoded[$i]);
    $a = $b ^ 123;  // <-- must be same number used to encode the character
    $decoded .= chr($a)
}
echo $decoded;
```

Comment: +1 Thank you Ridcully, I appreciate the effort and time you put into this.

Comment: how does the php side work ? new to this.. but confused with it saying "It works the same in PHP". When i look up XOR it has a key too

Comment: In PHP you do exactly the same as in Javascript. First, define a variable $decoded = "". Then you iterate over the characters of the encoded string and you do a bitwise XOR with the **same** number you used at Javascript side for encoding. Thus you get the original character again. You append the decoded character to $decoded and end up with the original string. It's all based on the fact that if you apply a bitwise XOR twice, you get the original value again.

Comment: @crosenblum I added a PHP snippet to my answer.

Comment: Currently line 3 of the PHP part is obsolete?!

Comment: @Möhre - Thanks, I removed the obsolete line. So for all others - there are no more obsolete lines in the php code.

Comment: very nice implementation +1 for this

Comment: Am I the only one who has problems with this code? If I use the number 123, then all "{" disappear from my string. Every char from ascii table will disappear, if I use their number from ascii table.

Comment: Bitwise encoding will result a pretty nasty character set which is not necessarily in the Latin dictionary. Isn't there any issue with passing this through http and later decoding in PHP?

Comment: can someone convert js (encode function ) into php function

Answer (score 8):

If it's not about security, and not about making it hard to break, then how about `ROT-13`?

```
//+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
//@ http://jsfromhell.com/string/rot13 [rev. #1]

String.prototype.rot13 = function(){
    return this.replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function(c){
        return String.fromCharCode((c <= "Z" ? 90 : 122) >= (c = c.charCodeAt(0) + 13) ? c : c - 26);
    });
};

...

var s = "My String";

var enc = s.rot13();  // encrypted value in enc
```

PHP has a native function, `str_rot13`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php

```
$decrypted = str_rot13($_GET['whatever']);
```

Comment: But OP want to use a `URL` as input. And `Rot-13` leaves the *non-alpha characters untouched*. This may output `/` and `:` characters but OP wants output in only *lowercase and numbers*. Also, as non-alpha chars are untouched, it is very very simple to predict that the encoded string is a URL.

Comment: @shamittomar, there was no comment about a URL as input when this answer was made.  I answered basically tongue-in-cheek based on the requirements.

Comment: the revisions of this question show that the initial post contained following: `...to change a string (a url) in a way...`. You may have missed it :) . No problem.

Answer (score 4):

Well I found this page and found Redcully's program not work for me so I thought It happens with all others. finally I got reason and fixed it. Here new code is...
Thanks to Redcully :)

## JS function:

```
function encode(str) {
  var encoded = "";
  for (i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
    var a = str.charCodeAt(i);
    var b = a ^ 51;    // bitwise XOR with any number, e.g. 123
    encoded = encoded+String.fromCharCode(b);
  }
  return encoded;
}
```

## PHP function:

```
function decode($encoded) {
  $decoded = "";
  for( $i = 0; $i < strlen($encoded); $i++ ) {
    $b = ord($encoded[$i]);
    $a = $b ^ 51;  // <-- must be same number used to encode the character
    $decoded .= chr($a);
  }
  return $decoded;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you planning to implement (hide) the secret in Javascript? IMHO it's not possible.

Edit: OK - not about security.. then just use any baseXX or rot encoding mechanism. But you can't really say one of these algorythms would not be well known...

Comment: The objective is not to hide the secret

Comment: @Majid whats the use of the encryption if the key is not secret?

Comment: I think he means hash not encrypt.

Comment: Well.. a hash has neither to do with secret and not with encryption at all. The OP clearly states that he want to encrypt something and adds: "Then I want to feed the encrypted string to a PHP function to change it back to the original".

Comment: @Max - It is to pass through more sophisticated filtering which decodes the proxified url to see what site is being accessed through a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple (no library needed) encrypt/decrypt method to/from PHP<->Javascript.

2 responses in this topic are on the right track - but they don't work because they don't take into account how PHP handles UTF encoding.
This is a fully tested/working example.

Javascript:

```
function _crypt(textToEncrypt) {

        var key = 128; // select any number, but make sure to match it in your PHP script
        var out = "";
        var c = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < textToEncrypt.length; i++)
        {
            c = textToEncrypt[i].charCodeAt(0) & 0xFF;
            c = (c ^ key);
            c = String.fromCodePoint(c);
            out += c;
        }
        return out;
    }
```

PHP:

```
function _crypt($textToEncrypt) {

    $key = 128;
    $out = "";
    $c = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($textToEncrypt); $i++) {
        $c = mb_ord(mb_substr($textToEncrypt, $i, 1));
        $c = ($c ^ $key);
        $c = mb_chr($c);
        $out .= $c;
    }
    return $out;
}
```