# Javascript XOR Encrypt | PHP XOR Decrypt

Tags: php, javascript, encryption, obfuscation, xor

I am looking for a simple and lightweight method of encrypting a string with javascript then decrypting with PHP after it's been sent in a header. **With code for both JS and PHP parts**.

There is no need for security as it's merely a means to obscure the string in the header.

XOR seems to be the best/lightest way. There are plenty of examples with incomplete answers.

The easiest answer seems to be the required PHP to decode this answer of the JS part: [Simple Javascript encrypt, PHP decrypt with shared secret key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609005/simple-javascript-encrypt-php-decrypt-with-shared-secret-key/3609208#3609208)

Open to any other lightweight methods.

Comment: if it isn't for security, then what *is* it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you XOR it, chances are you'll end up with invalid characters in your headers.

If you don't need security, what is wrong with good ol' [`base64_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)/[`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)? There are [plenty of Javascript equivalent codes](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+base64) out there...

Comment: Thanks, my question was pretty stupid in hindsight but this did the job in the end^