# Using Crypto-JS in Google Apps Script - What is C.lib?

Tags: javascript, c, google-apps-script, cryptojs

I would like to us `Crypto-JS` in Google Apps Script and have copied all source files into my project.

When trying to encrypt data with its `AES`, I can't get it to work because the following reference in `aes.js` is not valid in Google Apps Script:

```
var C_lib = C.lib;
```

This is my "JavaScript for Dummies" question (I am a JavaScript newbie) :-)

How can I reference and use `C.lib` with Google Apps Script?
What is `C.lib`? I have not found any good information on Google and SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `core.js`:

```
/**
 * Library namespace.
 */
var C_lib = C.lib = {};
```

It seems that every file from the package CryptoJS use it something like:

```
var C_lib = C.lib;
var WordArray = C_lib.WordArray;
var BlockCipher = C_lib.BlockCipher;
```

So, most probably you have to link `core.js` if you are using development version.

Example from [CryptoJS 3.1](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/)

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
</script>
```

works without any other links.

Comment: How do I link to external frameworks from within Google Apps Script? This does not seem to be possible.

Comment: Here [Using CryptoJS in google app](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/crypto-js/Iw_Wk5lju5o) a user claims _So it was as simple as copying the JavaScript into the google spreadsheet script page and going from there.  Works like a charm._

Comment: It seems that this user just copied necessary minified js files into his project and added his functionality. I make a copy of his project, it seems there is no way to link Crypto.js from outside.

Comment: It would be great if you would get the full Crypto-JS running in Google Apps Script (in particular AES encryption). Unfortunately I was not successful.

Answer (score 2):

- The main problem with importing external libraries in apps script is the sheer lack of any support for modules.
- The other problem would be unsupported classes/methods.

In case of cryptoJS,

- Dependencies need to be manually figured out. It is usually recorded in the first few lines of a script using `require` or `define`. The following links in script shows such lines.
- About unsupported classes, apps script doesn't support native `crypto` library that is present both in `node`  and `window`. In this case,  the problem cannot be circumvented AFAIK. Therefore It is not possible to use latest versions of CryptoJS. But older versions can be used.

#### Sample script:

```
function getCryptoJS() {
  const baseUrl = (file, version = '3.3.0') =>
    `https://unpkg.com/crypto-js@${version}/${file}.js`;

  const require = ((store) => (file) => {
    if (Array.isArray(file)) return file.forEach(require);
    if (store[file]) return;
    store[file] = true;
    eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl(file.slice(2))).getContentText());
  })({});

  /**
   * AES
   * @see https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/31d00127a7c87066c51abe56e7b8be3a32141cae/aes.js#L8 for dependencies
   */
  const dependenciesAES = [
    './core',
    './enc-base64',
    './md5',
    './evpkdf',
    './cipher-core',
    './aes',
  ];
  require(dependenciesAES);
  const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    'my message',
    'secret key 123'
  ).toString();

  /**
   * SHA3
   * @see https://github.com/brix/crypto-js/blob/31d00127a7c87066c51abe56e7b8be3a32141cae/sha3.js#L4 for  dependencies list
   */
  const dependenciesSHA3 = ['./core', './x64-core', './sha3'];
  dependenciesSHA3.forEach(require);
  const hash = CryptoJS.SHA3('Message');
  console.log({ ciphertext, hash: hash.toString() });
}
```

In a similar way, you can use all the supported methods in CryptoJS 3.3.0(=3.1.9-1)