# Google sheet: import a library (CryptoJS)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cryptography, cryptojs

I'm using the google sheet webscript to manipulate spreadsheet data and I want to use the following function to encrypt certain cells:

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("message", "Secret key");

There's an option to add libraries to the Google Sheet webscript but I have no idea how to get a library installed. According to the Google documentation you need the project key/script ID in order to use the library, but I have not been able to find this kind of information.

Can someone assist in how to actually import this CryptoJS library to use in the webscript.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Hello @MichaelTolsma, you might not need the `CryptoJS` library at all because if you want to encrypt certain cells you might make use of some of the methods presented in this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities). Cheers!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63647410/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that there are no built-in methods for directly achieving the AES encryption in Google Apps Script methods.

So in this case, how about the following workarounds?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, [crypto-js](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) is used.

#### Usage:

##### 1. Get crypto-js:

Please access to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js. And copy and paste the script to the script editor.

##### 2. Sample script:

After the copy and paste crypto-js, please copy and paste the following sample script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var key = "sampleSecretKey";
  var value = "sampleMessage";

  var encryptedMessage = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, key).toString();
  var decryptedMessage = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedMessage, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

  Logger.log(encryptedMessage);
  Logger.log(decryptedMessage);
}
```

- When you run the function of `myFunction()`, the encrypted and decrypted values are returned.

### Pattern 2: Updated on April 7, 2022.

In this pattern, ["cCryptoGS"](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/google-apps-scripts-snippets-2/cryptojs-libraries-for-google-apps-script/) which is a Google Apps Script library is used.

#### Usage:

##### 1. Install Google Apps Script library:

The project key for installing the library is `1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs`.

[Please install the GAS library using this project key.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#managing_libraries)

##### 2. Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var key = "sampleSecretKey";
  var value = "sampleMessage";

  var cipher = new cCryptoGS.Cipher(key, 'aes');
  var encryptedMessage = cipher.encrypt(value);
  var decryptedMessage = cipher.decrypt(encryptedMessage);

  Logger.log (encryptedMessage);
  Logger.log (decryptedMessage);
}
```

- When you run the function of `myFunction`, the encrypted and decrypted values are returned.

### References:

- [crypto-js at GitHub](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)
- [crypto-js at CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/crypto-js/3.1.2)
- [CryptoJS libraries for Google Apps Script](https://ramblings.mcpher.com/google-apps-scripts-snippets-2/cryptojs-libraries-for-google-apps-script/)
- [Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries)
- [cCryptoGS](https://github.com/brucemcpherson/cCryptoGS)

Comment: I can't get pattern 1 to work, but pattern 2 seems to be a good option. Thank you!

Comment: @Michael Tolsma Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Would you perhaps know if there is an "iv" value for this second method?

Comment: @Michael Tolsma Unfortunately, I'm not sure about it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. For example, how about asking it to the author of the library?

Comment: I ended up having to take the entire source code of AES part and add it as a separate file in my GSheet webscript. That way I could access CryptoJS methods directly as opposed to going through cCryotoGS.

Comment: The first project key is not working anymore, but thanks for your answer Tanaike. Very helpful, as usual

Comment: @Waxim Corp Thank you for your comment. From your comment, when I tested the "Pattern 2", I could confirm that the script works fine. But, in the current stage, it is required to use the project ID of `1IEkpeS8hsMSVLRdCMprij996zG6ek9UvGwcCJao_hlDMlgbWWvJpONrs` for installing the library. So I updated it.