# Stream third party audio through function in PHP laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I need a function that can stream audio from the third party website.

Suppose.

**Controller**

```
function getStreamAudio($id){ 
  $audioDetails = Audio::find($id);  //Get audio details
  $audio_full_url = $audioDetails->audio_path;  //www.otherdomain.com/abc/xyz.mp3
  //here i need to strem audio through id
}
```

I have a same playlist as below
**HTML**

```
<audio src="www.mydomain.com/stream_audio/1"></audio> // src tags are excute the above function
<audio src="www.mydomain.com/stream_audio/2"></audio> // src tags are excute the above function
<audio src="www.mydomain.com/stream_audio/3"></audio> // src tags are excute the above function
```

I have a playlist of the songs to stream audio. But purpose is to protect the audio original URL path.

I tried Defa Protector to encrypt the URL of audio. Below is the url

https://sites.google.com/site/defaprotectorhelp/

It's working, But when i add 4 or more songs in playlist. It shows me below error.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted
>   by a call to pause().

For this error also tried this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803176/how-to-prevent-the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-call-to-pause-error) solution. But still error is same.

When i use the original path of audio. It's working perfectly.

Comment: Is you dont want others to download your audio ?

Comment: Yes, I want to prevent download of audio.

Comment: For security (prevent access of original path), can make 2 step authendication (Encrypt/Decreypt URL).

Comment: For Stream audio, you need some javascripts to achieve.

Comment: Can you please suggest any javascript ? @Shankar Thiyagaraajan

Comment: For Simple Audio with JavaScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419263/playing-audio-with-javascript

Comment: For JavaScript Audio Doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: For 2 Way Encryption to Secure URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609005/simple-javascript-encrypt-php-decrypt-with-shared-secret-key